# Почему AJAX не отправляет данные?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlet

У меня простой ajax запрос который должен отправлять input на сервер через сервлет не перезагружая страницу. Но сервер не получает данные.

Объясните пожалуйста почему не работает и как это поправить?

Это моя станица:

```
<head>
    <title>home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#send_task").click(function(){

                var data = $("select#data").val();

                $.post('add_task', {data : data}, function(result){
                    $("#answer_from_server").html(result);
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="data">Enter the task</label><input id="data" type="text">
    <input id="send_task" type="button" value="Ok" />
    <p id="answer_from_server"></p>
</body>
```

И сервлет:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("data")); // всегда печатает null
         .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что если так (исправил селектор и полный URL поставил):

```
<head>
    <title>home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#send_task").click(function(){

                //var data = $("select#data").val();
                var data = $("#data").val();

                //$.post('add_task', {data : data}, function(result){
                $.post('http://test/add_task', {data : data}, function(result){
                    $("#answer_from_server").html(result);
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="data">Enter the task</label><input id="data" type="text">
    <input id="send_task" type="button" value="Ok" />
    <p id="answer_from_server"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Да проблема в селекторе спасибо, только полный путь не надо у меня папка защищена от прямого обращения только через сервлет работает.